# Json4s (Native/Jackson) Ignore all unknown fields

Tags: json, scala, jackson, json4s

When using Json4s it was very clear you can explicitly ignore specific fields. However, I don't see any documentation on how to ignore all unknown fields.

In Jackson, I would use the following annotation:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation._

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
case class MyClass(string: String)
```

How do I do this with either the Jackson or Native version of Json4s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, if I get you here, but Json4s (at least the org.json4s version) ignores additional fields by default.

```
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
case class Mailserver(url: String, username: String, password: String)

val json = parse(
"""
  {
    "url": "imap.yahoo.com",
    "username": "myusername",
    "password": "mypassword",
    "additional": "field"
  }
"""
)

val m = json.extract[Mailserver]
println(m.url)
println(m.username)
println(m.password)
```

This works fine.

Comment: Just curious what version of Scala are you using? And which version of Json4s? I noticed it was still giving me some trouble. Though I'd like to thoroughly test it.

Comment: For the test I was using version 3.2.11 of json4s and Scala 2.11.x. What kind of trouble do you have?

Comment: I was using the same version on Scala 2.10.x. I'm accessing a private API that changes structure/adds fields regularly, though I noticed it was still failing because some fields would appear. These fields are not type safe, so I try to avoid parsing them altogether.

Comment: So are you getting some sort of exceptions? Are they also removing / renaming fields? Or just adding new ones?

Comment: Yes, I don't have the log in front of me (sorry) but it was something like `no handler found for field 'x'`. Sometimes the field named `status` will be an `Int` of 200 and other times it is a `Boolean`. Also, fields of unknown name pop up every once in a while, so an explicit "ignore all" setting like in Jackson annotations would be quite helpful.

Comment: Hmm, as long as all fields of the object you want to extract are there, it should work I suppose. How do you handle the status field then? Is it an Int or a Boolean in your class?

Comment: I originally defined it as `Int`. I considered using `Either[Int, Boolean]` though it seems that the JSON equivalent is `{left:"", right:""}` so that doesn't work ;)

Comment: So I suppose you use String now? Since you can fit both in there? Btw. why don't you use jackson anymore?

Comment: Actually I reverted back to Jackson for this particular project :) I was hoping to take advantage of a Scala API though it didn't work out that way. However, the Json4s implementation of Jackson ignores annotations and it also fails to provide an API for the "ignore unknown fields" feature.

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't help you more on that topic.

Comment: Hey no problem. My guess is that Json4s native probably does exactly what's expected on the 2.11.x Scala version so I will accept your answer regardless :)